# Issues using grid-based movement and a collider tilemap

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a grid-based movement system that uses a tile map to find places where the player cannot move. Every tile on this tile map will be a place the player cannot move.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class GridMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool IsMoving = false;
    private Vector3 origPos, targetPos;
    public float moveSpeed = 0.2f;
    public Tilemap colliders;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       if (!IsMoving)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                StartCoroutine(MovePlayer(Vector3.up));
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {
                StartCoroutine(MovePlayer(Vector3.left));
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            {
                StartCoroutine(MovePlayer(Vector3.down));
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {
                StartCoroutine(MovePlayer(Vector3.right));
            }
        }
       
    }

    private IEnumerator MovePlayer(Vector3 direction)
    {
        IsMoving = true;
        float elapsedTime = 0f;

        origPos = transform.position;
        targetPos = origPos + direction;
        bool isTile = colliders.HasTile(Vector3Int.FloorToInt(targetPos));



        if (isTile == false)    
        {
            print("Worked");

            while (elapsedTime < moveSpeed)
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(origPos, targetPos, (elapsedTime / moveSpeed));
                elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
                yield return null;
            }
           
        }
        else
        {
            yield return null;
        }
       
        
       
        transform.position = targetPos;

        IsMoving= false;
    }
}
```

However the issue I am facing is that the player moves through the colliders and just moves to the other side.

I've tried using a movepoint to control where the player moved but this didn't work whatsoever (probably just be because my programming skill is limited) And I tried adding the else, yield return null but this did nothing.